# FCM Push notification not received on all devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have data notification and on some devices i always receive it,on some only when app is running and on one device i never receive it.

I set priority to high but nothing changes im not sure is it written proper, here is php code

```
$naslovPoruke = "Пробна апликација";
$path_to_fcm = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$server_key =my_key_here";
$key = "/topics/sve";

$msg = array
(
'title' => $naslovPoruke,
'body' => $poruka,
'idObjave'     => $idObjave,
'naslovObjave' => $naslovObjave,
'tekstObjave'    => $tekstObjave,
);
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
);
//$fields = array
    //(
    //  'to' => $key,
    //  'notification' => array('title'=>$naslovPoruke,'body'=>$poruka),
    //  'data' => $msg
    //);
$fields = array
    (
        'to' => $key,
        'data' => $msg,
        'priority'=>"high",
        'ttl'=>"0"
    );

$payload = json_encode($fields);
echo $payload;

$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL,$path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,$headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);

$result = curl_exec($curl_session);
echo $result;
curl_close($curl_session);
?>
```

Also this is json response:

```
    {
    "to": "\/topics\/sve",
    "data": {
        "title": "pushuptitle",
        "body": "pushupbody",
        "idObjave": "linktoimage.jpg",
        "naslovObjave": "apptitle",
        "tekstObjave": "appbody"
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "ttl": "0"} 
{
    "message_id": 6358638519123612486
}
```

Im not sure why i dont receive this message on all devices?

Comment: if few devices receiving then you should also focus on client implementation and OS versions.Since Android O you have to use Notification Channels to show notification .

Comment: What you mean by client implementation? I haven't tested on Android O,but i tested on android 4.2.2(minimum for app) , 4.x,5.x,6.x,7.x, i never receive on Huawei with 4.4 and i sometimes recieve it on Huawei 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if you have notifications enabled on the device that doesn't get the notification.

Comment: I dont think there is option for that on android 4.2.2 also on some devices it doesnt always appear